# How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Problem: Fragment `onResume()` in `ViewPager` is fired before the fragment becomes actually visible.

For example, I have 2 fragments with `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`. The second fragment is only available for authorized users and I need to ask the user to log in when the fragment becomes visible (using an alert dialog).

BUT the `ViewPager` creates the second fragment when the first is visible in order to cache the second fragment and makes it visible when the user starts swiping.

So the `onResume()` event is fired in the second fragment long before it becomes visible. That's why I'm trying to find an event which fires when the second fragment becomes visible to show a dialog at the appropriate moment.

How can this be done?

Comment: "i have 2 fragment with ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter. The second fragment can be available for authorized users only and i should ask use to login when the fragment becomes visible (alert dialog)." -- IMHO, that is awful UX. Popping up a dialog because the user swiped horizontally would cause me to give you a one-star rating on the Play Store.

Comment: is it better to just display information at TextView with "Login" button? What is your solution for that case?

Comment: Either log them in before they get to the `ViewPager`, or integrate the login into the to-be-secured fragment.

Comment: In general that does not make sense. Ok, imagine the next case: data loading takes a lot of time and you have to display ProgressDialog while loading. You have to display it at moment the fragment becomes visible. The problem is to determine when the fragment becomes visible.

Comment: You would not use a `ProgressDialog` with a `Fragment` in a `ViewPager`. You would use a `ProgressBar` widget as a placeholder for the fragment's content.

Comment: The point is that i don't know the time when i should start animation in ProgressBar or show ProgressDialog as onResume is fired long before .

Comment: You would start animation on the `ProgressBar` as soon as it is created. You would hide or remove the `ProgressBar` when it is no longer needed.

Comment: No need to load data if it will not be displayed. This loads CPU, increases traffic and drains battery and i will set one-star rating for such app.

Comment: "No need to load data if it will not be displayed." -- then you should not be putting it in a `ViewPager`. In a two-page pager, both pages will be loaded immediately, whether you like it or not. The user experience of `ViewPager` is supposed to be that the content is there immediately upon swiping, not some time later. That is why `ViewPager` initializes a page ahead of what is visible, to help ensure that user experience.

Comment: It seems that ViewPager is not flexible enough and it does not allow to turn off caching since minimum setOffscreenPageLimit is 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected. Don't see any reason for this and the expected behaviour (in case of compulsory caching) is to create fragment BUT fire fragment's onResume() when the fragment becomes visible.

Comment: I too am looking for a way to handle this "view is visible" event. I do not want to do this from the FragmentActivity using setOnPageChangeListener - so please tell me if there is another way.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your exploration, so what is the solution for such cases?

Comment: A bit late, but for anyone facing the same issue, you could try [FragmentViewPager](https://github.com/sbrukhanda/fragmentviewpager)  library (I am the author), which deals with this issue and provides a few extra features. For a sample, check project's GitHub page or this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38008088/5865280).

Comment: can anyone tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue-in-android

Comment: I handle the visible state at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207043/check-fragment-is-currently-visible-or-not-in-android/45059794#45059794. I split the Fragment's switch type into three ways, and if nested use, handle the sub Fragment's visible state in it's parent Fragment. It work for me.

Comment: here is the best way https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591019/5773037

Answer (score 610, accepted):

> How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager

You can do the following by overriding `setUserVisibleHint` in your `Fragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 fragments in viewstatepager and found getUserVisibleHint() always returns true.

Comment: getUserVisibleHint()?  My example with setsetUserVisibleHint should work fine by using the boolean paramater.

Comment: you should override setMenuVisibility as descibed by Oasis Feng. His answer should be voted up!

Comment: Actually I have tried this way before, but I found that not only the currently centered page, but also the pages before and after it got "user visible hint". So it may be suitable if your ViewPager shows more than one page at the same time (usually the case on tablet UI), but not for that shows only on page at a time.

Comment: Thanks to today's Android Support Library update (rev 11), the user visible hint issue is finally fixed. It's now safe to use user visible hint for ViewPager.

Comment: I haven't seen setUserVisibleHint() documented anywhere as a lifecycle event of the Fragment.

Comment: Looks like setUserVisibleHint is only for SupportLibrary, couldn't find it in latest SDK

Comment: when should i call this method?

Comment: You know, in Java a method is identified, in part, with a name (as you used), and a CLASS. So, please, when you suggest to override a method, please, please give the class. Especially as there are two objects that may be manipulated (`Fragment` and `ViewPager`).

Comment: I have found that the setUserVisibleHint method gets called BEFORE the onCreateView gets called and this makes it difficult to track any initialization.

Comment: @AndroidDev If you want to run some code when the hint's coming in as true, but which needs the view tree already initialized, just wrap that block of code in `isResumed()` to avoid an NPE. Been working fine for me.

Comment: A bit late, but for anyone facing the same issue, you could try [FragmentViewPager](https://github.com/sbrukhanda/fragmentviewpager)  library (I am the author), which deals with this issue and provides a few extra features. For a sample, check project's GitHub page or this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38008088/5865280).

Comment: Doesn't get called at all.

Comment: `setUserVisibleHint()` is not called when your App is paused on the fragment you want and you restart it from `onNewIntent()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue-in-android

Comment: Its just ridiculous that there are so many different hacks for something the SDK should provide by default.

Comment: Doesn't get called for me (SL 27.1.1)

Comment: `setUserVisibleHint` is now **Deprecated**

Comment: here is the best way https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591019/5773037

Answer (score 532):

**UPDATE**: Android Support Library (rev 11) finally [fixed the user visible hint issue](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/bf7974e46b008ffa4a16c61386735c4817d343aa), now if you use support library for fragments, then you can safely use `getUserVisibleHint()` or override `setUserVisibleHint()` to capture the changes as described by gorn's answer.

**UPDATE 1** Here is one small problem with `getUserVisibleHint()`. This value is by default `true`.

```
// Hint provided by the app that this fragment is currently visible to the user.
boolean mUserVisibleHint = true;
```

So there might be a problem when you try to use it before `setUserVisibleHint()` was invoked. As a workaround you might set value in `onCreate` method like this.

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setUserVisibleHint(false);
```

---

The outdated answer:

In most use cases, `ViewPager` only show one page at a time, but the pre-cached fragments are also put to "visible" state (actually invisible) if you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in `Android Support Library pre-r11`.

I override :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {
            // ...
        }
    }
   // ...
}
```

To capture the focus state of fragment, which I think is the most suitable state of the "visibility" you mean, since only one fragment in ViewPager can actually place its menu items together with parent activity's items.

Comment: Be carefull to use getActivity(), on first start it will be null.

Comment: Note that setUserVisibleHint() has always worked properly in FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: This solution (and also gorn's) is lagging a little bit. In cases where the viewpager is swiped quickly and mutliple times, this method will be called with a delay (when the fragment is no longer visible/invisible).

Comment: all above solution work once fragment visible completely..is there any way to know when it just get started to visible.

Comment: I am getting `true` for getUserVisibleHint() when `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called, and when `setUserVisibleHint` is called, the menu has not yet been been created it seems. Ultimately I get two options Menu's added when I only want the menu from the fragment that is visible. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: This is just to let anyone who's thinking of using this approach know that there's a delay of almost a second before your updates show up. My app is almost done and I'm not happy with the results on the phone. For some reason, this isn't very noticeable on the emulator but on the phone is very disconcerting. To give you an example, if you have a ListView setup with a TextView that shows up when the List is empty, when you swipe to that Fragment (with the backing data list now cleared) you'll see all the previous list items first and then they'll vanish with "no data/empty text" a second later!

Comment: A bit late, but for anyone facing the same issue, you could try [FragmentViewPager](https://github.com/sbrukhanda/fragmentviewpager)  library (I am the author), which deals with this issue and provides a few extra features. For a sample, check project's GitHub page or this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38008088/5865280).

Comment: Above new answer works fine but it must be noted that above answer would not work if you're working with transactions. It means the fragment which is created by a transaction, always is visible by default and that callback would be called.

Comment: `setUserVisibleHint` is now **Deprecated**

Comment: here is the best way https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591019/5773037

Answer (score 147):

This seems to restore the normal `onResume()` behavior that you would expect.  It plays well with pressing the home key to leave the app and then re-entering the app.  `onResume()` is not called twice in a row.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed())
    {
        //Only manually call onResume if fragment is already visible
        //Otherwise allow natural fragment lifecycle to call onResume
        onResume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!getUserVisibleHint())
    {
        return;
    }

    //INSERT CUSTOM CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: isResumed() was really helpful to get the desired result.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Solves the problem with `setUserVisibleHint` being called before `onCreateView` and that `setUserVisibleHint` doesn't get called if app goes background and then foreground. Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I think calling onResume yourself is a pretty bad idea, but otherwise, everything you need to answer the question of this post is in the setUserVisibleHint function !

Comment: Yea, I'd probably tend to agree; for this example I implemented like that only for the sake of simplicity.  You can create your own method onVisible or whatever you'd like to name it and call that method instead of onResume.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this together with some checks in addOnTabSelectedListener worked great for me.

Comment: I'd rather implement a plain `onVisibleToUser()` method and have that called from `onResume()` and from `setUserVisibleHint(boolean)` instead of calling `onResume()` myself and interfering with life-cycle callbacks.  Otherwise I think this approach works nicely, thanks!

Comment: Yes I agree with the above comments. In general, try to avoid calling public methods from public methods in your class. Make a private method and call it from both public methods.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Also who can post complete good practice code?

Comment: Best answer, Thank you.

Comment: setUserVisibleHint deprecated!

Answer (score 78):

Here is another way using `onPageChangeListener`:

```
  ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findByViewId(R.id.viewpager);
  FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPageAdapter(getFragmentManager);
  pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

  public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {
    // Just define a callback method in your fragment and call it like this! 
    adapter.getItem(pageNumber).imVisible();

  }

  public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
});
```

Comment: This solution works well, thanks.  This should be the recommended solution for those building for older platforms using the (v4) fragment support packages

Comment: It's worth noting that this could not give you the expected result if you're using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and instantiating a new Fragment instance on getItem(), because you would only be setting the state on the new fragment and not the one that the viewpager got

Comment: This solution is good if you want to perform something when the fragment becomes visible. It doesn't keep a fragment's visible state (meaning, it doesn't know when the fragment is invisible).

Comment: I am same type of problem. please help me to solve the problem. My Post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115283/change-fragment-with-viewpager

Comment: this is giving null pointer exception for adapter which i am using in the iamVisible method of the fragment. I am trying to set data received from network only when the fragment is visible.

Comment: This call seems to be deprecated.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867852/viewpager-setonpagechangelistener-deprecated

Comment: @AsafK If you have `ViewPager` in tabs for example, only one fragment would be visible at a time right? So can't we assume rest of them are hidden except the one for this the `onPageSelected` is called?

Answer (score 63):

In `ViewPager2` and `ViewPager` from version `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0` you can just use `onPause` and `onResume` callbacks to determine which fragment is currently visible for the user. `onResume` callback is called when fragment became visible and `onPause` when it stops to be visible.

In case of ViewPager2 it is default behavior but the same behavior can be enabled for old good `ViewPager` easily.

To enable this behavior in the first ViewPager you have to pass `FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` parameter as second argument of `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor.

```
FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
```

Note: `setUserVisibleHint()` method and `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor with one parameter are now deprecated in the new version of Fragment from android jetpack.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. I was looking for this from long time. Great Work

Comment: For ViewPager2 the option BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT is not the default behavior, you need to set it manually. When Setting this option your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: As of APR 2020 this is the updated solution and works like a charm.

Comment: @4ntoine please consider accepting this answer as the correct answer, since as of now this is correct and most answers are using the deprecated setUserVisibleHint method

Comment: I think it works well with FragmentStateAdapter as well. That's a huge relief for any android developer. Thanks to google for solving this after so long.

Comment: this is the best solution ever as long as you can use androidx fragment 1.1.0! thanks @lukjar

Comment: How do we determine if this onPause is because of ViewPager swiped or a dialog opened on top?!

Answer (score 57):

`setUserVisibleHint()` gets called sometimes **before** `onCreateView()` and sometimes after which causes trouble.

To overcome this you need to check `isResumed()` as well inside `setUserVisibleHint()` method. But in this case i realized `setUserVisibleHint()` gets called **only** if Fragment is resumed and visible, NOT when Created.

So if you want to update something when Fragment is `visible`, put your update function both in `onCreate()` and `setUserVisibleHint()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(...){
    ...
    myUIUpdate();
    ...        
}
  ....
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed()){
        myUIUpdate();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Still i realized `myUIUpdate()` gets called twice sometimes, the reason is, if you have 3 tabs and this code is on 2nd tab, when you first open 1st tab, the 2nd tab is also created even it is not visible and `myUIUpdate()` is called. Then when you swipe to 2nd tab, `myUIUpdate()` from `if (visible && isResumed())` is called and as a result,`myUIUpdate()` may get called twice in a second.

The other *problem* is `!visible` in `setUserVisibleHint` gets called both 1) when you go out of fragment screen and 2) before it is created, when you switch to fragment screen first time.

**Solution:**

```
private boolean fragmentResume=false;
private boolean fragmentVisible=false;
private boolean fragmentOnCreated=false;
...

@Override
public View onCreateView(...){
    ...
    //Initialize variables
    if (!fragmentResume && fragmentVisible){   //only when first time fragment is created
        myUIUpdate();
    }
    ...        
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed()){   // only at fragment screen is resumed
        fragmentResume=true;
        fragmentVisible=false;
        fragmentOnCreated=true;
        myUIUpdate();
    }else  if (visible){        // only at fragment onCreated
        fragmentResume=false;
        fragmentVisible=true;
        fragmentOnCreated=true;
    }
    else if(!visible && fragmentOnCreated){// only when you go out of fragment screen
        fragmentVisible=false;
        fragmentResume=false;
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`fragmentResume`,`fragmentVisible`: Makes sure `myUIUpdate()` in `onCreateView()` is called only when fragment is created and visible, not on resume. It also solves problem when you are at 1st tab, 2nd tab is created even if it is not visible. This solves that and checks if fragment screen is visible when `onCreate`.

`fragmentOnCreated`: Makes sure fragment is not visible, and not called when you create fragment first time. So now this if clause only gets called when you swipe out of fragment.

**Update**
You can put all this code in `BaseFragment` code [like this](https://gist.github.com/jemshit/749f4c3ae7156a387fda0a252028e219) and override method.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly except with one scenario, when the fragment is opened normally and then you click some button to replace it with another fragment and then click back to pop the new fragment from the backstack, it that case `setUserVisibleHint` didn't get call..! and inside `onCreateView` method the `fragmentVisible` was `false` !? so the fragment showed up empty..! any thoughts.?

Answer (score 35):

#### New

`ViewPager2` + `FragmentStateAdapter` + `onResume()` (in Fragment)
solve the problem

#### Old Answer (deprecated)

To detect `Fragment` in `ViewPager` visible, I'm quite sure that **only using** `setUserVisibleHint` is not enough.
Here is my solution to check if a fragment is visible or invisible. First when launching viewpager, switch between page, go to another activity/fragment/ background/foreground`

```
public class BaseFragmentHelpLoadDataWhenVisible extends Fragment {
    protected boolean mIsVisibleToUser; // you can see this variable may absolutely <=> getUserVisibleHint() but it not. Currently, after many test I find that

    /**
     * This method will be called when viewpager creates fragment and when we go to this fragment background or another activity or fragment
     * NOT called when we switch between each page in ViewPager
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mIsVisibleToUser) {
            onVisible();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mIsVisibleToUser) {
            onInVisible();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will called at first time viewpager created and when we switch between each page
     * NOT called when we go to background or another activity (fragment) when we go back
     */
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        mIsVisibleToUser = isVisibleToUser;
        if (isResumed()) { // fragment have created
            if (mIsVisibleToUser) {
                onVisible();
            } else {
                onInVisible();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onVisible() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), TAG + "visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onInVisible() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), TAG + "invisible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**EXPLANATION**
You can check the logcat below carefully then I think you may know why this solution will work

**First launch**

```
Fragment1: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=false isResumed=false
Fragment2: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=false isResumed=false
Fragment3: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=false isResumed=false
Fragment1: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=true isResumed=false // AT THIS TIME isVisibleToUser=true but fragment still not created. If you do something with View here, you will receive exception
Fragment1: onCreateView
Fragment1: onStart mIsVisibleToUser=true
Fragment2: onCreateView
Fragment3: onCreateView
Fragment2: onStart mIsVisibleToUser=false
Fragment3: onStart mIsVisibleToUser=false
```

**Go to page2**

```
Fragment1: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=false isResumed=true
Fragment2: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=true isResumed=true
```

**Go to page3**

```
Fragment2: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=false isResumed=true
Fragment3: setUserVisibleHint: isVisibleToUser=true isResumed=true
```

**Go to background:**

```
Fragment1: onStop mIsVisibleToUser=false
Fragment2: onStop mIsVisibleToUser=false
Fragment3: onStop mIsVisibleToUser=true
```

**Go to foreground**

```
Fragment1: onStart mIsVisibleToUser=false
Fragment2: onStart mIsVisibleToUser=false
Fragment3: onStart mIsVisibleToUser=true
```

[DEMO project here](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidDetectFragmentVisible)

Hope it help

Comment: It not works when a fragment has another view pager which also consists fragment.

Comment: sorry, I can not post the answer at this time because i don't have enough time, if possible please refer my git about your problem here https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidViewPagerSkeleton/tree/master. `SubChildContainerFragment` is used for detect `a fragment has another view pager which also consists fragment`. You can mix `SubChildContainerFragment` and `ChildContainerFragment` to 1 class. Hope it help. I will post the complete answer later

Answer (score 26):

```
package com.example.com.ui.fragment;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.com.R;

public class SubscribeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subscribe, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            // called here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works with android.app.Fragment also, which is a huge bonus.

Comment: `setUserVisibleHint` Deprecated

Answer (score 18):

Override `setPrimaryItem()` in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` subclass. I use this method, and it works well.

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // This is what calls setMenuVisibility() on the fragments
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

    if (object instanceof MyWhizBangFragment) {
        MyWhizBangFragment fragment = (MyWhizBangFragment) object;
        fragment.doTheThingYouNeedToDoOnBecomingVisible();
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost worked but had issues with NPE and being called multiple times. Posted an alternative below!

Comment: @kris http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue-in-android

Comment: @Gober saving Object object at first time,and check and ignore the follow up call with the same Object object just like FragmentStateAdapter do in setPrimaryItem() method

Answer (score 16):

Override [`Fragment.onHiddenChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged%28boolean%29) for that.

> `public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)`
>
> Called when the hidden state (as returned by [`isHidden()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isHidden())) of the fragment has changed. Fragments start out not hidden; this will be called whenever the fragment changes state from that.
>
> Parameters 
> `hidden` - `boolean`: True if the fragment is now hidden, false if it is not visible.

Comment: this method is deprecated by now and can not be used anymore

Comment: @bluewhile where do you see it is deprecated? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged%28boolean%29

Comment: I've just used this with success, and the documentation don't seem to indicate it's deprecated.

Comment: @bluewhile, in 4.1 (api 16) it is not deprecated yet.

Comment: I'm using API level 19 and can confirm that while this is not deprecated, it does not work as advertised. onHiddenChanged is not called when the fragment is hidden by another fragment, for example.

Comment: This method is not called.

Answer (score 9):

Only this worked for me!! and `setUserVisibleHint(...)` is now deprecated (I attached docs at end), which means most of other answers are deprecated ;-)

```java
public class FragmentFirewall extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Required cause "setMenuVisibility(...)" is not guaranteed to be
     * called after "onResume()" and/or "onCreateView(...)" method.
     */
    protected void didVisibilityChange() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (isResumed() && isMenuVisible()) {
            // Once resumed and menu is visible, at last
            // our Fragment is really visible to user.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        didVisibilityChange();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        didVisibilityChange();
    }
}
```

Tested and works with `NaviagationDrawer` as well,
there `isMenuVisible()` will always return `true` (and `onResume()` seems enough, but we want to support `ViewPager` too).

> `setUserVisibleHint` is deprecated. If overriding this method, behavior implemented when passing in `true` should be moved to `Fragment.onResume()`, and behavior implemented when passing in `false` should be moved to `Fragment.onPause()`.

Answer (score 8):

**setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)** is now **deprecated** So this is the correct solution

```
FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
```

In **ViewPager2** and **ViewPager** from version `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0` you can just use `onPause()` and `onResume()` to determine which fragment is currently visible for the user. `onResume()` is called when the fragment became visible and `onPause` when it stops to be visible.

To enable this behavior in the first ViewPager you have to pass `FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` parameter as the second argument of the `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor.

Comment: you are lifesaver mate , this is the best answer in 2021 as all the above answers are depreciated .

Answer (score 5):

I figured out that `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` methods called only in the case of the fragment *really* visible. I could not found any method which behaves like these, also I tried `OnPageChangeListener` but it did not work for the situations, for example, I need a variable initialized in `onCreate` method.

So these two methods can be used for this problem as a workaround, specifically for little and short jobs.

I think, this is the better solution but not the best. I will use this but wait for better solution at the same time.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution [posted here overriding setPrimaryItem in the pageradapter by kris larson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager/30945061#30945061) almost worked for me. But this method is called multiple times for each setup. Also I got [NPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Dereferencing) from views, etc. in the fragment as this is not ready the first few times this method is called. With the following changes this worked for me:

```
private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

    if (position == mCurrentPosition) {
        return;
    }

    if (object instanceof MyWhizBangFragment) {
        MyWhizBangFragment fragment = (MyWhizBangFragment) object;

        if (fragment.isResumed()) {
            mCurrentPosition = position;
            fragment.doTheThingYouNeedToDoOnBecomingVisible();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. It is calling only once. If again comeback to the same page, the mCurrentPosition and position are equal

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem while working with `FragmentStatePagerAdapters` and 3 tabs. I had to show a Dilaog whenever the 1st tab was clicked and hide it on clicking other tabs.

Overriding `setUserVisibleHint()` alone didn't help to find the current visible fragment.

When clicking from 3rd tab -----> 1st tab.
It triggered twice for 2nd fragment and for 1st fragment.
I combined it with isResumed() method.

```
    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isVisible = isVisibleToUser;

    // Make sure that fragment is currently visible
    if (!isVisible && isResumed()) {
        // Call code when Fragment not visible
    } else if (isVisible && isResumed()) {
       // Call code when Fragment becomes visible.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following Code inside fragment

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) 
 {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed()) 
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: This only works for ViewPagerFragments. Not for fragments in normal activity.

Answer (score 2):

We have a special case with MVP where the fragment needs to notify the presenter that the view has become visible, and the presenter is injected by Dagger in `fragment.onAttach()`.

`setUserVisibleHint()` is not enough, we've detected 3 different cases that needed to be addressed (`onAttach()` is mentioned so that you know when the presenter is available):

1. Fragment has just been created. The system makes the following calls:

   ```
   setUserVisibleHint() // before fragment's lifecycle calls, so presenter is null
   onAttach()
   ...
   onResume()
   ```
2. Fragment already created and home button is pressed. When restoring the app to foreground, this is called:

   ```
   onResume()
   ```
3. Orientation change:

   ```
   onAttach() // presenter available
   onResume()
   setUserVisibleHint()
   ```

We only want the visibility hint to get to the presenter once, so this is how we do it:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        lastOrientation = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LAST_ORIENTATION,
              getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
    } else {
        lastOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    }

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    presenter.onResume();

    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == lastOrientation) {
        if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
            presenter.onViewBecomesVisible();
        }
    }
    lastOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (presenter != null && isResumed() && isVisibleToUser) {
        presenter.onViewBecomesVisible();
    }
}

@Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_LAST_ORIENTATION, lastOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Detecting by `focused view`!**

This works for me

```
public static boolean isFragmentVisible(Fragment fragment) {
    Activity activity = fragment.getActivity();
    View focusedView = fragment.getView().findFocus();
    return activity != null
            && focusedView != null
            && focusedView == activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findFocus();
}
```

Comment: focusedView returning null.

Comment: @ATES Yeah I realized that there are some different situations which focusedView will be null. I'll try to find a new way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. `ViewPager` executes other fragment life cycle events and I could not change that behavior. I wrote a simple pager using fragments and available animations.
[SimplePager](https://github.com/rukmaldias/SimplePager)

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked !

```
mContext.getWindow().getDecorView().isShown() //boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

I support SectionsPagerAdapter with child fragments so after a lot of headache I finally got working version based on solutions from this topic:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean visible;
    private boolean visibilityHintChanged;

    /**
     * Called when the visibility of the fragment changed
     */
    protected void onVisibilityChanged(View view, boolean visible) {

    }

    private void triggerVisibilityChangedIfNeeded(boolean visible) {
        if (this.visible == visible || getActivity() == null || getView() == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.visible = visible;
        onVisibilityChanged(getView(), visible);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!visibilityHintChanged) {
            setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getUserVisibleHint() && !isHidden()) {
            triggerVisibilityChangedIfNeeded(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
        triggerVisibilityChangedIfNeeded(!hidden);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        visibilityHintChanged = true;
        if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed() && !isHidden()) {
            triggerVisibilityChangedIfNeeded(true);
        } else if (!isVisibleToUser) {
            triggerVisibilityChangedIfNeeded(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        triggerVisibilityChangedIfNeeded(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        triggerVisibilityChangedIfNeeded(false);
    }

    protected boolean isReallyVisible() {
        return visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, once you add child fragment to parent fragment    
 set fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);

Comment: And don't forget to use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() for adding child fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I was trying to get a timer to fire when the fragment in the viewpager was on-screen for the user to see.

The timer always started just before the fragment was seen by the user.
This is because the `onResume()` method in the fragment is called before we can see the fragment.

My solution was to do a check in the `onResume()` method. I wanted to call a certain method 'foo()' when fragment 8 was the view pagers current fragment.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 8){
        foo();
        //Your code here. Executed when fragment is seen by user.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. I've seen this problem pop up a lot. This seems to be the simplest solution I've seen. A lot of others are not compatible with lower APIs etc.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it uses a "magic number," which means it only works for Piyush's app.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `setUserVisibleHint(false)` is not called on activity / fragment stop.  You'll still need to check start/stop to properly `register/unregister` any listeners/etc.

Also, you'll get `setUserVisibleHint(false)` if your fragment starts in a non-visible state; you don't want to `unregister` there since you've never registered before in that case.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        // register
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        // unregister
    }

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        // register

        if (!mHasBeenVisible) {
            mHasBeenVisible = true;
        }
    } else if (mHasBeenVisible){
        // unregister
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of implementing that is checking whether user is logged in **before** going to the fragment.

In your MainActivity you may do something like this inside the **onNavigationItemSelected** method.

```
 case R.id.nav_profile_side:


                if (User_is_logged_in) {

                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                    , new FragmentProfile())
                            .commit();
                }else {

                    ShowLoginOrRegisterDialog(fragmentManager);

                }

                break;
```

However, if you are using navigation drawer, the selection in the drawer will have changed to Profile though we have not gone to the ProfileFragment.

To reset the selection to the current selection run the code below

```
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be very late. This is working for me. I slightly updated the code from @Gobar and @kris Solutions. We have to update the code in our `PagerAdapter`.

`setPrimaryItem` is called every time when a tab is visible and returns its position. If the position are same means we are unmoved. If position changed and current position is not our clicked tab set as -1.

```
private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(@NotNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NotNull Object object) {
    // This is what calls setMenuVisibility() on the fragments
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    if (position == mCurrentPosition) {
        return;
    }
    if (object instanceof YourFragment) {
        YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) object;
        if (fragment.isResumed()) {
            mCurrentPosition = position;
            fragment.doYourWork();//Update your function
        }
    } else {
        mCurrentPosition = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Kotlin**

```
override fun onHiddenChanged(hidden: Boolean) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden)

    // Your code goes here..
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I overrode the Count method of the associated FragmentStatePagerAdapter and have it return the total count minus the number of pages to hide:

```
 public class MyAdapter : Android.Support.V13.App.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
 {   
     private List<Fragment> _fragments;

     public int TrimmedPages { get; set; }

     public MyAdapter(Android.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm) { }

     public MyAdapter(Android.App.FragmentManager fm, List<Android.App.Fragment> fragments) : base(fm)
     {
         _fragments = fragments;

         TrimmedPages = 0;
     }

     public override int Count
     {
         //get { return _fragments.Count; }
         get { return _fragments.Count - TrimmedPages; }
     }
 }
```

So, if there are 3 fragments initially added to the ViewPager, and only the first 2 should be shown until some condition is met, override the page count by setting TrimmedPages to 1 and it should only show the first two pages.

This works good for pages on the end, but wont really help for ones on the beginning or middle (though there are plenty of ways of doing this).