# ViewPager with fragments - onPause(), onResume()?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onresume, onpause

When using `ViewPager` with fragments, our `onPause`, `onResume` methods are not called when moving between tabs. Is there any way we can figure out in the fragment when we're being made visible or being hidden?

Unfortunately I have logic in `onResume`, `onPause`, like registering with location services, that never get stopped when switching tabs because `onPause` never gets called until one exits the whole app.

Comment: Good simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35450575/2162226 .. explains how to override for Fragment: `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` to know if "current" tab view is showing

Answer (score 18):

The ViewPager comes with the [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface.  By setting some flags for the previous and currently shown pages, you can emulate this behavior.

Comment: Could you give a bit more info?

Comment: I suppose during OnPageChange() callback, you could set the UserVisiblityHint to true on the new fragment selected and to false on the old fragment. Then calling their respective onResume() and onPause() methods. The user visibility hint then needs to be checked in onResume() to ensure the call is made during onPageChange instead of the standard all during fragment creation.
Is there a real flag to recover the documented behavior though?

Comment: Sorry mate, been out of town. Glad someone came through!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845641/alternative-for-the-onresume-during-fragment-switching

Answer (score 10):

Considering previous solutions are not very clear, here is how I solved it thanks to Phix for his hint:

In the OnPageChange() callback:

```
    Fragment old_fragment = getActiveFragment(old_position);
    Fragment new_fragment = getActiveFragment(new_position);
    old_f.setUserVisibleHint(false);
    old_f.onPause();
    new_f.setUserVisibleHint(true);
    new_f.onResume();
```

Then in onResume():

```
    if (getUserVisibleHint())
        /* resume code */
```

and in onPause():

```
    if (!getUserVisibleHint())
        /* pause code */
```

Here is the getActiveFragment code, avoiding to search for that too:

```
    return fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + position);
```

NB: Fragment have a isVisible() method, but it doesn't seem to be very consistent, hence the use of UserVisibleHint.

EDIT: Replace the UserVisibleHint by a private flag. Worked much better!

Comment: Sure it's not a good solution, but there's no other at the moment to work-around this OS "bug" or behavior. Why fragments have onResume() onPause() but it's never called in the first place?

Comment: It is not a OS bug. This means the `Fragment` is still in memory. `ViewPager` will retain in memory at least 2 `Fragments` do to its paging nature. Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11650582/2029566) for more details.

Comment: Hence I also said "behavior". Note sure what your comment or link you provide add to the discussion though. The problem is that one need a way to know when the fragment is shown/hidden, which I implemented more or less this way, except I call some private onVisible and onHidden methods. If you know of a better solution, why not write your own? The only 2 answers to this question are more or less the same.

Comment: And it's definitely a bug, if you take a look at Fragment reference (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). basically, onStart() makes the fragment visible to the user, onResume() makes the fragment interacting with the user, onPause() fragment is no longer interacting with the user, onStop() fragment is no longer visible to the user. Those are only called when the fragments are created, which have nothing to do with them being visible.

Comment: The proper solution would be to perform the logic in the OnPageChangeListener. onPause and onResume are for when the activity moves in and out of the background not for visibility changes.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Android Support Library (rev 11), you can use `getUserVisibleHint` or override [`setUserVisibleHint`()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) to capture the changes visible and hide. Look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager).

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // do something when visible.
    }
}
```

Comment: override this method in the fragment

Answer (score 6):

Current version of `ViewPager` library allows to enable the desired behavior out of the box, just pass `FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` as [second argument](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter#FragmentPagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20int)) to [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter).

Also consider using [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2?hl=en) that came to replace `ViewPager`. `ViewPager2` calls `onPause()` and `onResume()` as expected by default, no configuration required.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57888432/4858777) fore more details.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:**

Define a `SparseArray` in your `ViewPagers`' adapters like below. In this array we'll hold the instance of fragments.

```
SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();
```

And `Override` your Adapters' `instantiateItem` method.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}
```

Also `Override` `destroyItem` method of your `ViewPagers`

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
```

And define a new method to get your `ViewPager` `Fragments` instance.

```
public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}
```

Now you can implement your logic with `ViewPager's` `OnPageChangeListener`.
Here's an example about how you can implement a viewpager's `onPageChangeListener`:

Define an integer to keep current position:

```
int currentPos;

yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // Empty method
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                  // This is paused fragment.
                  final Fragment pausedFragment = yourAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(currentPos);

                  // update current position value
                  currentPos = position;

                  // This is resumed fragment
                  final Fragment resumedFragment = yourAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(currentPos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Empty method
            }
        });
```

Finally for restoring instance state update your current position to keep updated in which position user left `ViewPager`

```
currentPos = yourViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

**Solution 2:**

For another solution you can find your `ViewPager` `Fragments` by `Tag`. You can generate your tag with:

```
@NonNull
public static String generateViewPagerFragmentTag(int viewPagerId, int position) {
        final StringBuilder tagBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        tagBuilder.append("android:switcher:");
        tagBuilder.append(viewPagerId);
        tagBuilder.append(":");
        tagBuilder.append(position);
        return tagBuilder.toString();
    }
```

And find your `Fragment`:

```
final Fragment yourFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(generateViewPagerFragmentTag(R.id.your_viewpager, currentPos));
```

**Edit:**

A few years ago while i was looking a solution for getting `ViewPager`'s current item I tried `userVisibleHint` in `Fragment`s and noticed that it was not reliable. I'm not sure if it's reliable or not now but still I avoid to use.

Comment: more callbacks introduces more errors, simple use viewpager2 any version above 1.00 .You can simple handle things in onResume when you swipe, since onRes will only be called once you swipe to particular fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below method in `Fragment`

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser){

}
```

when `isVisibleToUser == true`, the fragment is shown

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the perfect solution to this.

when you are initialising your adapter do it like this:-

```
    import static androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT;

//(i am using androidx but if you have not yet migrated yet you can use appcompat)

    adapter = new FeedTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
```

After adding this line you'll be getting your onResume() and onPause callbacks perfectly. Please mark it correct solution if this issue is solved by my code .Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use Viewpager2 latest versions, it will call onResume() only when you scroll to that fragment, alike Vp1 which calls it before for +1 next fragment.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but in my current app I've set the OffScreenPageLimit to 1 for my viewpager, this means the fragments are not cached and each time the view changes it reloads the current fragment

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getOffscreenPageLimit()

Answer (score 0):

To give a bit more definition to the methods in [savepopulation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559852/savepopulation)'s answer:

```
yourPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new GridViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int row, int column, float rowOffset, float columnOffset, int rowOffsetPixels, int columnOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int row, int column) {
            // When on page selected if position is not specific for you
            // you can find your fragment or you can switch position.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```