# Update ViewPager total pages and set current item without reloading

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm sorry if the title is ambiguous as I don't know how to describe my problem in a short way.

I'm using `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to display a list of posts of a forum's thread. Each page of the `ViewPager` is corresponds to a page of the thread. There are some types of link that lead to the thread without specifying the page, for example: `showthread.php?t=12345&goto=newpost`, which means that I can only get current page and total pages after loading that link. Assume that the link will lead to page 5 and there are 10 pages, my current flow is:

1. `ViewPager` has 1 page initially
2. Load the link and notice that current page is 5 and total pages is 10
3. Update total pages and notify `ViewPager` using `viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`. This causes `ViewPager` to load page 2 automatically
4. Jump to page 5 using `viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);`. This causes `ViewPager` to load page 4, 5 and 6 automatically

So I end up with 2 redundant requests (for loading page 2, and page 5 again (the first time is through the link). Is there any ways to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

It's default behaviour of viewpager to load previous and next page

`ViewPager pager= (ViewPager)findView....
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`

Check link for more detailed answer

[ViewPager offscreen page limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650152/viewpager-offscreen-page-limit)