# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00c4

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I want to pass some List from fragment into 2 other fragment. When i pass data to fragment two it is going well. But it is error when pass to the fragment three

Error code

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp, PID: 15267
>                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00c4 (com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp:id/fragment3) for
>   fragment ThreeFragment{e045027 #3 id=0x7f0d00c4}
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1415)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:702)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5555)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)

Pass Code in OneFragment.java

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putStringArrayList("keys", keys);
                    //set Fragmentclass Arguments
                    Fragment fragobj=new TwoFragment();
                    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag2, fragobj).commitAllowingStateLoss();

                    Bundle bundle2=new Bundle();
                    bundle2.putStringArrayList("keys", keys);
                    //set Fragmentclass Arguments
                    Fragment fragobj2=new ThreeFragment();
                    fragobj2.setArguments(bundle2);
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment3, fragobj2).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

the first pass into TwoFragment did well. But the second pass gave me error like that. Please help me. I have been check all of the id in the ThreeFragment.xml and all correct.

ThreeFragment.java

```
package com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {
    View v;
    private List<DaftarPengumuman> listPengumuman = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> obj3 = new ArrayList<>();

    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(getArguments()!=null)
        {
            obj3 = bundle.getStringArrayList("keys");
            Log.e("nba",obj3.toString());
        }



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }
}
```

fragment_three.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.ThreeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Three"

        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.java that is stored the viewpager

```
package com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private List<MataKuliah> listMatkul = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    private myAdapter myAdapter;
    private Button logoutBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private TextView mTextName;
    private TextView mTextNim;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    static {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }

    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    FirebaseUser users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference mataKuliahRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("courses");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        //Navbar menu
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.navbaraction);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawabel_main);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
        View header = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        mTextName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.header_name);
        mTextNim = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.header_nim);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Tab Layout
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case (R.id.tugas):
                        break;
                    case (R.id.logout_menu):
                        signOut();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        userRef.child(users.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String nim = (String) dataSnapshot.child("nim").getValue().toString();

                mTextNim.setText(nim);
                mTextName.setText(name);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };


    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Beranda");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Tugas");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Pengumuman");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {

            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);


    }

}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawabel_main"
    tools:context="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                layout="@layout/navbar_action"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="304dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/MainRView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="444dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="LOGOUT"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.945"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navbar_main"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navbar_header"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: They don't find the view I think is `R.id.fragment3` are not logic to `R.id.frag2` for me so I think is can be `R.id.frag3` if is not that can we see the xml `fragment_three`.

Comment: There is no problem there,the three_fragment.xml I'd is fragment3. I have been change the name before.

Comment: Do you know if your fragment three is create before call it. Because I having the same problem and is because the fragment has not be created. `onCreate()` method has be call

Comment: If you use ViewPager see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650152/viewpager-offscreen-page-limit `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)`

Comment: "the three_fragment.xml I'd is fragment3" – If you mean that the `ViewGroup` with ID `fragment3` is in the `three_fragment` layout, that's the problem. The `R.id` you pass to a `replace()` call is for the `ViewGroup` that the `Fragment` will be put into, not one inside the `Fragment`'s own layout.

Comment: Yes I have tablayout with view pagger sir, so what should I do? @MikeM.

Comment: I'm not sure, as I'm not certain of your actual setup. If you mean that `OneFragment`, `TwoFragment`, and `ThreeFragment` are all in your `ViewPager`, then you're not approaching this correctly. The only reason the above code worked for `TwoFragment`, I suspect, is because `ViewPager` loads one page ahead, so there is already a `TwoFragment` created, and a `frag2` in its layout attached. If that's the case, what's really happening is that you're putting a new `TwoFragment` inside the original `TwoFragment` that was created by the `PagerAdapter`. Instead of creating and transacting new...

Comment: ...`Fragment`s, you should instead pass the `ArrayList` to the existing ones, somehow. This is all speculation, though. You'd need to provide more details about your overall setup for someone to be able to give you a specific solution.

Comment: wait sir I will give u more code @MikeM.

Comment: OK, since you're trying to update existing `Fragment`s, you won't be able to use their arguments to do that. You could add a public method in each – e.g., `setKeysList(List<String> keys)` – then set up an interface between `OneFragment` and the `Activity` to pass the list to the `Activity`, and from there to the other two `Fragment`s. There's an example of how to implement such an interface on [this developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#DefineInterface).

Comment: I'm sorry sir,I'm really new on the fragment. Can u give me more specific or the code @MikeM

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm on my phone, atm. Hopefully somebody else will be along to help.

Comment: I still dont have any solution..