# How to clear EditText when swiped tab in tablayout

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In `TabLayout` there are 4 tabs. At 2nd tab I have `EditText`(for search).When entered some text in `EditText` and when swipe to another tab again and I come back to watch `EditText`, whatever I entered text which is not cleared. But I want to clear `EditText` when swiped to other tab.

[Please watch this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9lbM.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far? post some of your code for the ViewPager / Adapter. are you already using `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`?

Comment: Is this a `viewpager` or 4 buttons in `horizontal linearlayout` ?

Comment: Yes I am using ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.I have doubt that is when I swipped to another tab, onResume() or onPause() methods are not getting called.

Comment: No , it's viewpager @buzzingsilently

Comment: ok but viewpager is located in activity,but edittext is in fragment. Is it possible to change fragment's views by Activity?

Comment: setText("") in `onresume()` method of fragment.

Comment: @Lokeshkrishna I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845641/alternative-for-the-onresume-during-fragment-switching will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your edittext fragment..

```
@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {


        }
        else
        {       
        edittext.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onResume() of the fragment clear the edittext like this.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        yourEditText.getText().clear(); //or yourEditText.setText("");
    }
```