# Fragment onPause() is not called when my app is minimized multiple times

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have fragments inside a `ViewPager`. When I minimize the app, it will call `onPause()` on the Fragment inside the `ViewPager`, then when I resume the app, it will call `onResume()`. But when I minimize it again, `onPause()` is not called anymore.
Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: can you tell me your requirement dear ?

Comment: Maybe help you with the following link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853611/viewpager-with-fragments-onpause-onresume

Comment: What does it mean by **When I minimize the app**? by pressing home key ?

Comment: @quicklearner I have some things to do on my `onPause()` method e.g. settings dialogs to null, etc. But the problem is:

Comment: can your post relevant code here , i will help you with your requirement dear

Comment: **when opening the fragment inside the viewpager**:
-> Parent Fragment: `onResume()`, Child Fragment: `onResume()` 
**minimize the app (click home button)**:
-> Parent Fragment:` onPause()`, Child Fragment: `onPause()` 
**open it again**:
-> Parent Fragment: `onResume()` is called but Child Fragment's `onResume()` is not called anymore
**minimize the app (click home button)**:
-> Parent Fragment: `onPause()` is called, but Child Fragment's `onPause()` is not called anymore

Comment: I can't understand the lifecycle of the childfragment. why is it not resumed when its parent fragment is already resumed?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the cause of my problem. On the `onStop()` of the Parent Fragment, they have put this code:

```
try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class
                .getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I don't know the purpose of this but it seems to be a workaround for the bug in supporting nested fragments.
[Getting the error "Java.lang.IllegalStateException Activity has been destroyed" when using tabs with ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed/15656428#15656428)

In the link above, it suggests to add this code on `onDetach()`. But it seems that they have mistakenly placed it on `onStop()`.

When I transferred the above code to `onDetach()`, there is now no problem with the child fragment's lifecycle.

It's scary because I am only supporting this project and I am not the one who created it in the first place. I just hope that this won't have any side effects. Thank you so much to everyone who gave their answers/suggestions. I appreciate it. :)