# Fragment In ViewPager OnPageSelected() Or OnPageShow()?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is Fragment in ViewPager has a equivalent method like `OnPageSelected()` Or `OnPageShow()` ? I should do something when a specific page is showing?

---

I set hidden state of each Fragment in `onPageScrolled()` In page adapter, and I wonder why `onHiddenChanged(`) not be called?

// In PageAdapter(extends FragmentPagerAdapter)

```
    public void onHiddenChanged(int arg0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            if (i == arg0) {
                mAdapter.getItem(arg0).onHiddenChanged(true);
            } else {
                mAdapter.getItem(arg0).onHiddenChanged(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

// in PageActivity(extends FragmentActivity)

```
public void onPageSelected(int arg0)
{
    mAdapter.onHiddenChanged(arg0);
}
```

Comment: Solved!@see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager/12523627#12523627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Android` for `ViewPager` there is a `listener` called `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` which has methods like

```
onPageScrollStateChanged(int state),

onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) , 

onPageSelected(int position)
```

If you want to do some specific task for the page you need to write `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and override `onPageSelected(int position)` method.

for more details [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

Comment: Solved! @see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager/12523627#12523627

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). You get a callback when the page is changed, example:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // this will be called when the page is changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to call in Fragment not FragmentTabsActivity, so?

Comment: Solved! @see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager/12523627#12523627