# Fragment become visible

Tags: android

Each time my fragment become visible to the user I want to execute a peace of code that will call a web service, fetch some data and display it on the screen. I got the web service part etc working but not sure in what event I must add my code.... I tried:

1. onStart
2. onResume
3. onAttach

But my code doesn't fire everytime.

Am using the Android v4 comp lib with SherlockFragment as my base class.

Comment: same problem here. Documentation says that onResume is called only once after onCreateView(). There seems to be no event on fragment when you add a fragment to a FragmentManager(). I don't see how to do. I suppose we have to use FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() but from Frament point of view, no issue :(

Answer (score -17, accepted):

`onResume()` is called every time your fragment becomes visible to the user. There is something else wrong with your code if it doesn't

`onCreateView()` is called the first time the fragment needs to draw its UI

**Update**: This accepted answer was working 5 years ago - it doesn't anymore

Comment: You should look at Fragement documentation. There is a huge difference with activities. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

Comment: The answer is wrong. As far as I tried: I have a FragmentActivity and using a ViewPager in that activity. The ViewPager contains 4 Fragments. Whenever my app starts (only the 1st Fragment is visible), both the methods : onCreateView() & onResume() of the 1st & 2nd  Fragements are called !

Comment: Is that not exactly what I said? onResume is always called - also when the app starts (the first time) along with onCreateView

Comment: @Lieuwe Please consider removing this answer as it is misleading for people who checs for the right answer

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer. Please refer to the Android documentation: "onResume - Called when the fragment is visible to the user and actively running"   and  "onCreateView() - Called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view".

Comment: @hungson175 ViewPager will create the fragment by default +-1 from currently visible fragment because it will be faster to transition to when swiping. You can override this functionality and have the fragment only be created when you actually select that tab (and be destroyed immediately when moving away)

Comment: Unfortunately onResume is not always called.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If the answer is not relevant you could always update it or add a note explaining why it won't work.

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { }
    else {  }
}
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)

Comment: this is API 15 and over :( boo

Comment: doesn't work when you push the back button with nested fragments

Comment: Doesn't work for me in a tab-layout. It also gets called for the following tab which is not yet visible to the user.

Answer (score 3):

This may be very old but I found setUserVisibleHint() didn't work for many of my use cases. Instead I had to resort to a hack using the ViewTreeObserver.

Basically, after your fragment is initialised, you get a view within it and do the following:

```
myViewInFragment.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            myMethodWhenFragmentFirstBecomesVisible();
            myViewInFragment.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onCreateView()`

Called Every time when you change the Fragment and new Fragment become visible..

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: Take a look and let me know, What happened?

Comment: Well I was stuck with this problem and tried lots of different ways but this one was the solution!

Comment: @keybee - Its only called when you transaction the fragment with two fragment and fragment newly created.

Comment: @user370305 Yes, but if I understand it right, the questions was about how to get notified about a fragment being visible to the user. (the problem here is for example that you can create a lot of fragments, and if you go back to your previous fragment using the back stack, `onCreateView` will never be called.

Answer (score 2):

Below method is used determine when Fragment becomes visible in the front of a user.

```
private boolean loding= false; // your boolean flage

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isFragmentVisible) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(true);
if (this.isVisible()) {
    // we check that the fragment is becoming visible first time or not
    if (isFragmentVisible && !loding) {
       //Task to doing while displaying fragment in front of user
        loding = true;         
    }
}}
```