# ViewPagerIndicator - onActivityCreated called before swipe

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I currently have a viewpageindicator with three tab 1,2 and 3. 
The problem is when i swipe to tab 2, the onActivityCreated from fragment 3 is being called.

At my tab 3 fragment, i will call a  asyntask onActivityCreated , therefore when fragment 2 is being switched, it will load a asyntask.

Comment: Why is this a problem? ViewPagers have to load pages to the left and right of the visible page to let you see the content when swipeing.

Comment: the reason why this is of a problem is that fragment 3 will call a alertdialog and asyntask which will cause problem when i switch to fragment 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ViewPagers load one Fragment on either side of the current Fragment. To know when a Fragment is in the centre, you could use the onPageChangeListener of the ViewPager in combination with an interface implemented by every Fragment subclass.

```
public interface FragmentChangeListener
{
void onCentered();
}
```

Implement this interface in every Fragment

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentChangeListener
{
....
 @Override
 public void onCentered()
 {
 //Show alertDialog and start asyncTask
 }
}
```

In your Activity class:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position)
  {
    FragmentChangeListener listener = (FragmentChangeListener) //cast fragment at this position to FragmentChangeListener
    listener.onCentered();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to determine if the fragment is visible or not to decide whether you should show your dialog box or not. You can get an idea of how to do that here: [How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)

It's possible you should consider redesigning this interaction, the viewpager was designed to easily swipe between views and poping up dialog boxes could prove to be a confusing interaction.