# Example of using google analytics with fragments?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to use google analytics within a fragment for tracking screen views. I don't understand where we should allocate a Tracker instance. The doc on manual screen tracking leaves us with  this example:

```
/**
 * Within an Activity or Fragment
 */
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ... // Your other onStart() code.
    myTracker.sendView("Home Screen"); // Where myTracker is an instance of Tracker.
}
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens

Where is "myTracker" defined? What is its lifecycle? I'm looking for a skeleton Fragment that shows the lifecycle of the "myTracker" variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`myTracker` is instance of `Tracker` which you can get from `EasyTracker.getTracker()`

This is URL to concrete jar
https://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/list

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering where in a Fragment you would allocate "myTracker". Could you provide a skeleton example of a Fragment that uses a tracker? This is what's missing from the documentation.

Comment: There is no method called getTracker() in EasyTracker class.

Answer (score 0):

[Probably this might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883613/using-google-analytics-to-track-fragments) Must say you should to search better. Anyway the main point is using of `sendView()` method.