# Hiding/showing the contextual action bar programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, contextual-action-bar

**My use case:**

I have an activity with a `ViewPager` as its only view element, set up with three `Fragment`s for its three pages (using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`). One of these fragments is a `ListFragment`, while the other two regular `Fragment`s containing some infographics.

The list in the `ListFragment` allows "checking" elements, and checking elements brings up the contextual action bar, presenting a list of actions possible on the selected/checked items.

**My problem:**

When I select a couple of list items, the CAB shows up. But when I switch pages, the CAB stays visible, presenting the actions. To make matters worse, the `ViewPager` seems to sometimes destroy the view of the list fragment - hence selecting the actions throws a `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created"` exception.

**My questions:**

1. How do I get the CAB to disappear when the user moves away from the `ListFragment` page?
2. (optional) How do I get the CAB to reappear when the `ListFragment` back is and some items are still checked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first add a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` with `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to your `viewPager`.

In the **onPageSelected** method call a method in your `ListFragment` to dismiss your CAB.

**EDIT:**

To get the current active fragment you can use it's tag. The tag can be computated with this method:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
   return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}
```

where viewId is the id of the viewpager and index the tab index (position)

Comment: How would you access the appropriate ListFragment from the ViewPager?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add the information on how to access the fragment

Comment: How come ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener is there twice?  Is that a typo or is it supposed to mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can also react to the fragment being hidden from inside the fragment by using the method setUserVisibleHint, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075663/1199911