# Dismiss the Contextual Action Bar When Nav. Drawer is Toggled

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-actionbar

The [official page for the Navigation Drawer design pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) states:

> Sometimes the user will be in a state where a contextual action bar
>   (CAB) appears instead of the app’s action bar. This typically happens
>   when the user selects text or selects multiple items after a
>   press-and-hold gesture. While the CAB is visible, you should still
>   allow the user to open the navigation drawer using an edge swipe.
>   **However, replace the CAB with the standard action bar while the navigation drawer is open. When the user dismisses the drawer,
>   re-display the CAB.**

But after researching I can't seem to find a way to "dismiss" the Contextual Action Bar inside my

```
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    // ... My Code ...
}
```

method.

In my case a CAB (with copy, paste, etc. options) may appear when a user selects text from an `EditText` in an `Activity` which itself displays a Nav. Drawer.

I've seen [this question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288278/hiding-contexual-action-bar-while-navigation-drawer-is-open) but it doesn't quite fix my problem as it's related to a custom ActionMode. How can I "dismiss" the CAB - the one that shows up when a user selects text - whenever the navigation drawer is toggled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You have to grab a reference to the `ActionMode` when it is created, and the `ActionMode.Callback` in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    mActionMode = mode;
}

@Override
public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onActionModeFinished(mode);
    mActionMode = null;
}

@Override
public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    mActionModeCallback = callback;
    return super.onWindowStartingActionMode(callback);
}
```

Then when your drawer opens/closes, finish the `ActionMode` or start a new `ActionMode` from the `ActionMode.Callback`:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    if (mActionModeCallback != null) {
        startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about the existence of those callbacks. Thanks! 
Your answer makes perfect sense but I can only test it later. I will accept it or give more details as soon as I'm able to.