# Dismiss the Contextual Action Bar When Nav. Drawer is Toggled and show it again

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar, contextual-action-bar

How can I do the same [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475559/dismiss-the-contextual-action-bar-when-nav-drawer-is-toggled/23491407) with `FragmentActivity`? In my case `public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)` is never called =/. I think is because I am using AppCompat.