# Navigation View combined with Contextual Action Mode?

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-navigationview, android-actionmode

New apps from Google, with Material Design, that use a Contextual Action Mode together with a Navigation Drawer.
Starting to swipe the NavigationView in, will temporary hide the ActionMode which will be re-enabled when the drawer is closed again.

In this video: [navigation drawer in gmail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vkMlno8kZ0) - look at the toolbar changing because of the navigation drawer swipe.

But how to implement this behavior? The only callback from NavigationView is OnNavigationItemSelected but what we need is maybe a callback from starting to open the drawer and then finishing closing it.

Could other solutions exist, that elude me? For example:

- perhaps draw a new toolbar over instead disabling the CAB?
- or even is it possible to make the CAB only overlay the Toolbar but not the NavigationView ([question still open here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663853/how-to-make-the-contextual-actionmode-bar-overlay-the-appcompat-v7-toolbar-but-n))

I am using:

- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
- android.support.v7.view.ActionMode

Comment: I can't get to your linked video, but if by "swipe" you mean opening and closing the drawer, `DrawerLayout` provides the [`DrawerListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) interface.

Comment: Thank you! Good start. And apologies for the video it's now accessible