# How to make ActionMode aligned with custom Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-actionmode

I have an activity with new support Toolbar and navigation drawer. The Toolbar relates to the content e.g. list of items. Multiple items can be selected - then ActionMode is shown (Context Action Bar). However the system ActionMode position, size and layout order does not correspond to the Toolbar, which would be appropriate.

Question is: how can I adjust the system ActionMode to correspond to (be aligned with) my Toolbar? Or is there any other recommended alternative? See my cases below

**Portrait**

NavDrawer may be hidden in side (1-green) - this is OK for both Toolbar and ActionMode.
Both Toolbar and its content are overlapped by the navigation drawer the drawer is opened (2-yellow). However, when ActionMode is active, it is displayed always over the NavDrawer (3-red), but I want it to look like (2-yellow), because the ActionMode is related to the hidden content.

This issue is similar to this question:
[How to make the Contextual ActionMode Bar overlay the appcompat-v7 Toolbar but not the navigation drawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663853/how-to-make-the-contextual-actionmode-bar-overlay-the-appcompat-v7-toolbar-but-n)

[image: ActionMode portrait]

**Tablet/landscape**

In landscape the NavDrawer fits next to the toolbar and content (left). The ActionMode always overlays the NavDrawer and Toolbar and has full screen width (right-red). Again I would like the ActionMode to be in the same position as Toolbar is (left-yellow).

[image: ActionMode landscape/tablet]

Comment: Maybe you have to finish ActionMode. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288278/hiding-contexual-action-bar-while-navigation-drawer-is-open

Comment: Thanks for hint, but this only seems like workaround. Not exactly what I want to achieve. It would be helpful only in the portrait case, not in tablet/lanscape scenario

Comment: I solved it with reflection. Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483778/display-actionmode-over-toolbar/30662727#30662727

Comment: I "solved" this by implementing as Google did with Gmail and Keep: as soon as the DrawerLayout calls the onDrawerSlide() I close the ActionMode. You can re-start the ActionMode once the drawer is fully closed.

Comment: I know this is not a proper solution, but I had the same problem and I managed it by temporary disabling the Drawer by `drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);` in actionModeCallbacks and then re-enabled the drawer after I finised my stuff with Action mode by calling `drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);`

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using another `Toolbar` (`actionModeToolbar`), which I can put anywhere in layout and show or hide it as appropriate.

I found some useful hints how to use `Toolbar` here:
https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/ae63392e1c70bc33af8b

Here is how I created `ActionMode` using `Toolbar` with legacy `ActionMode.Callback`. I have used methods similar to system `ActionMode` for partial compatibility.
Note, that `ActionMode.Callback` is not required anymore, because system `ActionMode` is not used and code can be refactored.

```
class ToolbarActionMode {

    Toolbar actionModeToolbar;
    ActionMode.Callback callback;       

    void startActionMode() {
        actionModeToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                toolbarActionMode.finishActionMode();
            }
        });
        actionModeToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return callback.onActionItemClicked(null, menuItem);
            }
        });
        // will create menu using inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_res)
        callback.onCreateActionMode(null, null);
        invalidate();
        actionModeToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    void finishActionMode() {
        callback.onDestroyActionMode(null);
        actionModeToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
    }

    void invalidate() {
        // will update title + menu
        callback.onPrepareActionMode(null, actionModeToolbar.getMenu());
    }

    void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        actionModeToolbar.setTitle(title);
    }

    void inflateMenu(int menuRes) {
        actionModeToolbar.inflateMenu(menuRes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at the same issue you described in your examples. Is this still the solution you care currently using or did you find something new ?

Comment: Basically we still use custom Toolbar to emulate the action mode. The code may have changed, but the idea is still the same.