# Viewpager OffscreenPageLimit issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've multiple choice (radio buttons) questions on pages. I'm getting user answers with hashmap. So I set previous question answer on start of next question. As a result I start using set hashmap on start 2.page.

BUT problem is: I think viewpager loads first 2 pages at the same time ; so "set hashmap" on start 2.page goes null ; because 1. page isnt loaded / or just loaded at the same time

How can I get rid of this problem ?

> 1. page: list answers (1)
> 2. page: get user choice(1), clear list(1),  set list answers (2)
> 3. page: get user choice(2), clear list(2),  set list answers (3) ...

maybe setoffscreenpagelimit 0 could be solution but lowest value is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager) can probably help you. 
Basically you just want to know when another fragment is visible, and update it from there.