# Change Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using `PagerSlidingTab` Library for `ViewPager`. And I want to change Fragment while scrolling of tabs. It is working fine. Check out my code.

I am using `AsynTask()` on each `Fragment`.
When the App opens with the MainActivity, First Fragment is attached to the activity, But It shows two `AsynTask()` dialog message, one from First and another from Second `Fragment`. And When I scroll to second tab, It shows dialog message of Third `Fragment`.

So, If I scroll from left to right in tabs, the `Fragment` right to the current fragment is displayed and if i scroll from right to left, the `Fragment` left to the current `Fragment` is displayed.

Please help me to solve the problem.

**My Code:**

```
public class PageSlidingTabStripFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = PageSlidingTabStripFragment.class
            .getSimpleName();

    public static PageSlidingTabStripFragment newInstance() {
        return new PageSlidingTabStripFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        private final String[] TITLES = { "Instant Opportunity", "Events",
                "Experts" };

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new InstantOpportunity();
            case 1:
                return new Events();
            case 2:
                return new Experts();
            default:
                break;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation:

It turns out there is an easier implementation for scrollable tabs which doesn't involve another library. You can easily implement tabs into your app using normal Android code straight from the default SDK.

## The Code

#### Main Class:

```
public class PageSlidingTabStripFragment extends Fragment {

    //Variables
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip;

    public PageSlidingTabStripFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //Find your pager declared in XML
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Set the viewPager to a new adapter (see below)
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager()));

        //If your doing scrollable tabs as opposed to fix tabs,
        //you need to find a pagerTitleStrip that is declared in XML
        //just like the pager
        pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip)
            getView().findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.[your layout name here], container, false);
    }

}
```

#### Adapter:

```
//Note: this can go below all of the previous code. Just make sure it's
//below the last curly bracket in your file!
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (arg0 == 0) {
            fragment = new InstantOpportunity();
        }
        if (arg0 == 1) {
            fragment = new Events();
        }
        if (arg0 == 2) {
            fragment = new Experts();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Instant Opportunity";
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            return "Events";
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            return "Experts";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Conclusion:

I hope this helps you understand another way to make scrollable tabs! I have examples on my Github Page about how to make each type (That being Fixed or Scrollable).

#### Links:

1. Fixed Tabs Example - [Click Here](https://github.com/AMQTech/Fixed-Tabs)
2. Scrollable Tabs Example - [Click Here](https://github.com/AMQTech/Scroll-Tabs)

Hope this helps!

#### Edit:

When asked what to import, make sure you select the V4 support fragments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But as I am using PagerSlidingTab library using SherLockFragment for Sliding menu using tab. So how can i solve this ?

Comment: I am using this : https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip

Answer (score 0):

please use this example..its very easy.i already implement that.

[reference link](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

hope its useful to you.its best example of pager-sliding-tabstrip.

Use

```
framelayout compulsory:
FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        fl.addView(urFragementView);
```

and then set your fragement view in this framelayout.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but here I am using Navigation Slider using PagerTabStrip so I cant use that thing. I have already tried it.

Comment: and almost my code is same, but they are showing textview, do u have any sample by which i open fragment instead of that ?

Comment: there is no error, If i am showing textview then it is fine. like this : `FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
  fl.setLayoutParams(params);

  fl.setView(textview);` but here, i want to open fragment...

Comment: urFragementView stands for ?