# Notify fragment`s view childs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have some fragments that I need to run some animations when they get visible.

Those fragments are inside a ViewPager. Thanks to that answer - [How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager/11075663#11075663) - I know that I get notified when my fragment is visible by the method getUserVisibleHint.

Because I have a lot of animations, I made custom views that know how to animate itself. And now I need to notify all the views inside the fragment in the method getUserVisibleHint of the fragment to they know that is time do animate themselves.

So my question is:
How can I notify all the views inside a fragment?

Any solution is welcome, but how I said, the views that I need to notify are custom views created by me, so I believe that I need some kind of custom notification too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said all your views are custom. I'm assuming they all implement a specific interface (lets say, `InterfaceA`).

The following code will call the `notificationMethod()` on every custom view that implements your `InterfaceA` interface. The `viewGroup` is your root view (for example, a `LinearLayout`).

```
int childcount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
   View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i); 
   if (view instanceof InterfaceA) { 
       ((InterfaceA)view).notificationMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest instead of a direct cast: `View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i); if (child instanceof InterfaceA) { ((InterfaceA)child).notificationMethod();`. That way it will continue gracefully if there are any views in the layout that do not implement the interface.