# How to save and restore FragmentPagerAdapter state in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 3 Fragment bind by FragmentPagerAdapter in a FragmentActivity,when I am switching to different app and after coming back to my app or after a incomming call the Fragments are not restoring to previous state,one fragments are completely disappeared and some of the fragments button click is not working..but in emulator its working fine

Kindly help me....

Comment: Everytime is it refreshing???

Comment: I dont understand.what do u mean by refreshing?

Comment: Means all the default data is loading while you switch tab??

Comment: Yes but for not switching tab,for switching app..

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18845616/1051783) will help you ... The poster had a similar issue.

Comment: @KousiK can you get any solution?

Comment: @Pintu Its happening to low version phones otherwise its okay..

Answer (score 4):

Override `onActivityCreated` in `Fragment`..

This method will be called when you come back to fragment

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            // Do your stuff
}
```

And add this line to your parentActivity of all Fragments  :

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

And switch to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` insteasd of using `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: I am creating the view in onCreateView then what should I do with onActivityCreated?

Comment: To maintain the save data, you can do ur code in onActivityCreated