# How can i use Fragment with nested fragments properly?

Tags: android, android-activity, transactions, fragment

I have 4 fragments and inside one fragment i have a viewpager and a different class where i define the viewpager's adapter with 3 other fragments, the first time when i open this fragment all the sub fragments show properly inside viewpager but when i switch (i use transaction.replace) to another fragment and i return again here the sub fragments are gone, i cannot use ChildFragmentManager as it shows error on code (ChildFragmentManager cannot be resolved to a type(i have latest support library updates)), how can i load these sub fragments everytime i show this fragment ?

here are some of my code :

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainfragment1, null);
        mPager = (ViewPager) view
            .findViewById(R.id.fMainPager);
        mPagerAdapter = new SubFragmentMainPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        // mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        return view;
    }
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class SubFragmentMainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
FragmentManager fragMan; 


public SubFragmentMainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int e) {
    switch (e) {
    case 0:
        return new SubFragment_1();

    case 1:
        return new SubFragment_2();

    case 2:
        return new SubFragment_3();
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}
```

}

Comment: I think this will definitely help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386254/viewpagers-fragments-view-lost-when-viewpagers-parent-fragment-hidden-then-sh

Comment: @Trivial thanks for support but i have an issue with getChildFragmentManager();

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`
2. Switch to `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` using `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager`
3. Now use `getChildFragmentManager()` for nested fragments
4. And in case you still haven't, switch to `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Actually all my fragments are using support.v4

Comment: where i can read more about AppCompatActivity ? i've never seen that before

Comment: did you also use `getSupportFragmentManager`?

Comment: That means something in your app is not from support libraries, did you try using [AppCompatActivity](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) instead of ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity

Comment: i tried now with SupportFragmentManager but now the current sub fragment's view goes and from 3 sub fragments it shows only 2 and if i try again to switch fragment i remain with only 1 sub fragment

Comment: AppCompatActivity also shows me that cannot be resolved to a type, what is going wrong ? i have installed my support library updates from sdk manager

Comment: Do you have support-v4 22.1.+?

Comment: As i saw in SDK MANAGER i have support-v4 23.1.1 installed