# Load data when Fragment is showing in Actionbar with Navigation tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have this huge data in 7 `Navigation Tabs`. My problem is all the Tabs load simultaneously instead of one Tab at a time.
I tried using `onHiddenChanged(boolean isHidden)` but its not been called.

Comment: this may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11075663/1400119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
          if(isVisibleToUser) { 
             To do what is required to load data 
      } else {
             Do nothing
       } 
   }
```

This method will gets called when u select each tab.
Override this method in every tab fragment activity.