# OnPageChange fragment inside viewpager inside fragment called before onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager inside a fragment. Inside the inner fragment i have to show animation when the fragment is visible. i checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager) and tried `setUserVisibleHint` and `OnPageChangeListener` both this are called before `onCreateView` and gives null pointer exception. how can i find when Fragment becomes visible in `ViewPager` so that i can start animation.

Answer (score 0):

@bill gates, viewpager is the thing, in that both page (Current page and next or previous page) both are prepare simultaneously itself,  so when you slide the current page two pages are visible to user. that a awesome function of viewpager. thanks.