# Check when Fragment is visible inside a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

There's a way to know when a fragment is effective drawn (and become visible to user) inside a FragmentActivity? 
Because i need to get coordinates of some wiews inside fragment, and i need that it is visible before do that

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager

Comment: They talk about ViewPager, and i don't have a viewpager !

Comment: The ViewPager is moot - you can use the setUserVisibleHint on the fragment. You can then expose that via public method to your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `Fragment` `onCreateView` you use following:

```
View view = ...

view.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         // do stuff
    }
});

return view;
```

I hope I remembered the syntax all correct from the memory :)

Comment: for accept answer i need to wait some minutes before. StackOverflow policy!