# Android how to know when your tab has gained focus,

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have a tab view in my activity,

Currently I am doing a UI update in my fragments `onCreateView` but I don't think this is the correct place.

Is there a method I can overload which will be called when my tab gains view? So that when my user clicks on or scrolls to my tab, I can then poll my server and update my view.

Some simplified code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Rhino68PanelActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

static String TAG = "Rhino68PanelActivty";

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rhino68_panel);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Network.cancelRequests(Rhino68PanelActivity.this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rhino68_panel, menu);
    return true;
}   

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0: {
            fragment = new OneSectionFragment();
        }
            break;
        case 1: {
            fragment = new TwoSectionFragment();
        }
            break;
        case 2: {
            fragment = new ThreeSectionFragment();
        }
            break;
        default: {
            fragment = new OneSectionFragment();
        }
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "1";
        case 1:
            "2";
        case 2:
            "3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class oneSectionFragment extends Fragment {


    private static Context mContext;

    public StatusSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rhino68_panel_status, container, false);
        mContext = getActivity();
        // update view
        ....
        return rootView;
    }
    //fucntions and methods
}

    public static class twoSectionFragment extends Fragment {


    private static Context mContext;

    public StatusSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rhino68_panel_status, container, false);
        mContext = getActivity();
        // update view
        ....
        return rootView;
    }
    //fucntions and methods
}
```

Comment: Add a tabchanged event, then you know which tab is active

Comment: How do I then call a method inside the fragment?

Comment: make a public method inside your SectionsPagerAdapter: onTabSelected(int index). Then you should store your fragment that you use in getItem(int position) like this: private OneSectionFragment oneSectionFragment; Next: you make a public function in your fragment and you can call it. Using a switch, you can select the right fragment.

Comment: Care to post an answer.

Comment: I need to post the answer? that was the answer, or not clear enough?

Comment: Its a comment, Not an answer, I cant click accept, and therefore you gain some rep. just a suggestion

Comment: Is my comment clear enough? else i'm going to right it down more clearly as an answer. But nice to gain some rep :)

Comment: Answer posted, if you need something more with your ViewPAger, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem 1: know which tab has focus

Solution: setOnPageChangeListener on your ViewPager. With the received index, you know which tab is active.

Problem 2: how to execute a method from the active page (fragment)

Solution:

1. create a public method in your viewpager adapter: onNewTabSelected(int index)
2. create your tab fragment accessible in your adapter (private MyTabFragment tabFragment;)
3. with the index, you know which Fragment you should use
4. create a public method in your Fragment
5. execute this method in the new created method inside your adapter

Comment: `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated in favor of `addOnPageChangeListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your view in each SectionFragment by using:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { }
    else {  }
}
```

@see: [How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)

Comment: I have tried this, but this function gets called even before the `onCreateView()`