# Change image in unfocussed ViewPager Fragment

Tags: java, android, otto

So I have a view pager implemented like this
[image]

In the main view I have button at the top right of the screen thats similar to a navigation bar. When I click it or swipe it I want it to disappear and when it refocuses on the main screen I want it to appear again. I've been trying it for hours and have had no luck.

I know I need to use `setVisibility(View.GONE)/VISIBLE` I just keep getting null pointers or the image just wont change.

Ive implemented `OnPageChangeListener()` and tried using otto events to change the button state as well, but the event is never being received.

In short the main goal is to be able to interact with elements on any view not visibly shown in the ViewPager

Comment: try to use ArrayList<Fragment> and when you are in **OnPageChangeListener()**, do things which you want to do with previous and next Fragments.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar worked perfectly

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand you!

Comment: Im saying that worked!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I will move this comment to answer and please mark it as answer to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `ArrayList<Fragment>` and when you are in `OnPageChangeListener()`, do things which you want to do with previous and next Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I have been encounter this problem days ago, I override `setUserVisibleHint()` finally solve it.

```
public class YourFragement extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

someone said override `setMenuVisibility()` also work, but I haven't try it, more information discuss in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075663/1294681).