# how to make view pager only resume selected fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have 4 fragments in my viewpager and each fragment is shown in each tab and I have 4 tabs. When I click my third tab or swipe to third tab, I find that, the fourth fragment's onresume method is executed, everytime I swipe through fragments, I see that the next page's on resume is executed.

I only want to execute selected fragment's on resume, not the fragment next to it, I searched a lot, but I cannot find a way to do it, is there a way to do it ? thank you

Comment: Post the code which causes the fragment associated to the tab to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, the viewpager requires at least one fragment to the left and one to the right.
I suggest you move the onResume() logic to a separate method and call it when the fragment becomes visible.

Try this : [How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)