# How do I control focus and scroll position when a fragment is returned to (onResume not called)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

I have 3 tabs in a ViewPager in my main activity. When I return to Tab 1 from Tab 2, I'd like to scroll to the top and put focus in the first EditText. However, Tab 1's `onResume` fragment method is not being called, so where can I set the view? Thanks.

Here is the code in my Activity where I set the `onPageChangeListener`.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    mPagerAdapter.getItem(position).onResume(); // trying to call onResume
                }
            });
```

This is my Fragment's `onCreate`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_new_grade_calc, container, false);

    context = this.getActivity();

    bindAll();     // map ScrollView and other views as Java Objects
    setListeners(); // set listeners for objects

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        setRestoredViews(savedInstanceState);
    } else
        setInitialViews(); 


    return rootView;
}
```

My Fragment's `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollview_new_grade);
         // ^^this is what gets the NullPonterException

    sv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sv.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my [answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075663/3165621).

Override this callback. I had to check to make sure my view was non-null to avoid problems on first load.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { }
    else {  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have Ontabselcted method or onpageselected method in that you can scroll to top.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I've tried calling `onResume` in `onPageSelected`, but I'm getting a NullPointerException when referencing one of my member variables that I define in my `onCreate`. I'm still new to a lot of this.

Comment: I've added what I think is relevant code. Let me know if you'd like anything else. Thanks.