# ViewPager Current Fragment Visibility

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-lifecycle

**What I Have**

I have a ViewPager with 5 fragments. I want to animate some TextViews inside the fragments whenever they become visible to the user.

I can't use onResume() as the fragments to the left and right are already created. I can't use setUserVisibilityHint() as it is called before onCreateView() so the views are not ready yet.

So what should be the way to animate the views whenever a particular fragment becomes visible to the user?

Comment: Have you tried ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()? animate the views when onPageSelected is called

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but if you say that `setUserVisibilityHint` calls before `onCreateView`, than check view on null here (make reference on view - field), and if it not null - animate it. Also animate it always in `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 1):

> **(1)** I can't use onResume() as the fragments to the left and right are already created. 
>   **(2)** I can't use setUserVisibilityHint() as it is called before onCreateView() so the views are not ready yet.
>
> So what should be the way to animate the views whenever a particular fragment becomes visible to the user?

You're right on (1) and (2). However, **`setUserVisibilityHint()` gets called Once Again** with a **True** value after the Fragment comes to Front on Display. But on First Run the Fragment to be shown gets its `setUserVisibilityHint()` called before `onCreateView()`.

SOL: You should use the above said behaviour of `setUserVisibilityHint()` along with `onResume()` to animate the views whenever a particular fragment becomes visible to the user.

- *Scenario 1*:  On First Run: Displayed Fragment's `setUserVisibilityHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` gets called with
  True param value. But as the Fragment's State is not Resumed we postpone and let the `onResume()` handle animation.
- *Scenario 2*: For Other Fragments that are already in Resume State, `setUserVisibilityHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` will get called with
  True param it they come on to Display. Here you check for the
  Fragment Animated or not and Do animation.

---

**CODE**

a) Declare two Global Boolean Fields: `isAnimated` and `isOnDisplay`

a.1) Set `isAnimated` boolean to True;

b) Override `setUserVisibilityHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`:

Here you set `isOnDisplay` boolean to `isVisibleToUser` and check is the Fragment Not Already Animated and is in Resumed State and is Visible to User.

```
{ if(!isAnimated && isResumed() && isVisibleToUser) // DO Animation }
```

c) Override `onResume()`

Check if the Fragment Not Already Animated and is Visible to User.

```
{ if(!isAnimated && isVisibleToUser) // DO Animation }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer might be a bit late, but I hope it can help others in a similar situation.

You could use [FragmentViewPager](https://github.com/sbrukhanda/fragmentviewpager) library (I am the author), which deals with the issue you are facing for you. Its features are:

- allows its `Fragment` pages to get notified when they are actually
  visible/invisible to the user
- supports multiple levels of `FragmentViewPagers` (nesting)
- provides methods to control its paging

A basic usage would be:

1. Attach `FragmentViewPager` programmatically or via XML to an Activity
   or Fragment, as you would with native `ViewPager`
2. Set `FragmentViewPager`'s adapter. Your adapter should inherit
   `com.sbrukhanda.fragmentviewpager.adapters.FragmentPagerAdapter` or
   `com.sbrukhanda.fragmentviewpager.adapters.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
3. Override `onResumeFragments()` of the hosting Activity and call
   `FragmentViewPager.notifyPagerVisible()`:

   ```
   private FragmentViewPager mFragmentsPager;

   @Override 
   public void onResumeFragments() {
       super.onResumeFragments();
       mFragmentsPager.notifyPagerVisible();
       ... 
   }
   ```

   or `onResume()` of the hosting Fragment and call
   `FragmentViewPager.notifyPagerVisible()`:

   ```
   private FragmentViewPager mFragmentsPager;

   @Override 
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       mFragmentsPager.notifyPagerVisible();
       ... 
   }
   ```
4. Override `onPause()` of the hosting Activity or Fragment and call
   `FragmentViewPager.notifyPagerInvisible()`:

   ```
   private FragmentViewPager mFragmentsPager;

   @Override 
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       mFragmentsPager.notifyPagerInvisible();
       ... 
   }
   ```
5. Implement `FragmentVisibilityListener` on all Fragment pages that you
   wish to receive callbacks for their visibility state
6. You are ready to go!

If you wish to see a more complete sample code, then check project's [sample project](https://github.com/sbrukhanda/fragmentviewpager/tree/master/demo).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in individual fragments, then you can use `isVisible()` 
for each fragment in your fragment transition and create a listener. Whenever a fragment will become visible , listener will be invoked and each fragment will implement that listener and do your intended task in the overridden method.

Comment: I want to do that in the individual Fragments, not on the Activity.

Comment: @Aritra : sure allow me some time.

Comment: Yes, sure. Will wait for it.

Comment: Don't understand what the difference with my solution