# Why does my recyclerview not update when I go to the next tab?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

So basically I have two tabs in a `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` to store two fragments in a tab view.

Thing is, I am using a `card view` in a `recycler view` and the `card view` has like a `Like Button`. Basically when the user clicks the button, it should appear on the next tab - but it doesn't. It is only when the user comes out of the entire page and goes back onto it and selects that tab does the selected `card view` is displayed. I checked my database and it is doing what it should be, but it is the `recycler view` that doesn't update.

This is my code for `liking` the contents in a `card view`:

```
 IN CUSTOM ADAPTER CLASS
 holder.likebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Database database = new Database(fragment.getContext());
                database.likeContent(userID, contentID, name);
            }
        });

DATABASE CLASS
public void likeContent(int userID, int contentID, String name){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(USER_ID, userID);
    contentValues.put(CONTENT_ID, contentID);
    contentValues.put(NAME, name);
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

BACKGROUND CLASS
public void showFavourites(final ArrayList<Integer> likes){
        theURL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(fragment.getActivity());
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (theURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                ...
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                }
                );
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

SECOND TAB CLASS
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.likes, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rlikes);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        adapter = new CAdapter(list, SecondTab.this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        conditionNames = new ArrayList<>();
        Background = new Background(SecondTab.this, list, adapter);
        inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        populate();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void populate(){
        background.showFavourites(inputs);
    }
```

So after I click the `like` button in the `Custom Adapter Class` it updates in the `database` but it doesn't update the `recyclerview` in the second tab.

EDIT: My pager adapter:

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    String tabNames[] = new String[] {"Current", "Likes"};
    Context context;

    public PodcastGUITabAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new CurrentTab();
            case 1:
                return new LikesTab();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabNames[position];
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: post pager adapter code. Most likely you need to return a new instance of fragment in getItem function.

Comment: @vipulmittal, I have edited my question to include the `getItem()` function

Comment: Put the code related to populating list from onCreate to onResume. Also if that not works  check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it using Broadcasts.

I registered [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in both tabs.

Then after updating the database I send a broadcast and it gets received by both tabs and in onReceive method I reload the data into recycler view.

**How to use Broadcasts (all this code goes into YourFragementClass):**

First you need to declare a broadcast:

```
public static final String BROADCAST_NAME = "com.yourapp.broadcast_name";
```

*Sending a broadcast:*

```
getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(BROADCAST_NAME));
```

*Registering a broadcast receiver:*

```
private static IntentFilter broadcastIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_NAME);
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            YourFragmentClass.this.refreshRecyclerAdapter();
        }
    };
private boolean broadcastReceiverRegistered = false;
```

*Also you need to unregister and reregister receiver in `onDestroy()` and `onResume()`:*

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, broadcastIntentFilter);
        broadcastReceiverRegistered = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(broadcastReceiverRegistered) {
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            broadcastReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

You should implement `YourFragmentClass.this.refreshRecyclerAdapter();` method something like this:

```
private void refreshRecyclerAdapter() {
        List<Items> items = getYourItems();
        ItemsRecyclerAdapter adapter = new ItemsRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```