# android prevent fragment leave on back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onbackpressed

I have a `ViewPager` inside a `FragmentActivity`. For each page I have a `Fragment` with an `EditText`.

I want to prevent the user leaving the screen if the `EditText` value has changed, showing a warning `Dialog` asking if he/she really wants to leave the screen.

For that I need to check the `EditText` value when the back `Button` is pressed.

I have only found how to do it but using the `onBackPressed()` method in the container `FragmentActivity`.

The problem is that I don't know how to access the `EditText` inside the `Fragment` from the parent `FragmentActivity`.

Is it not possible just to do it in the `Fragment`? I've tried the method `onStop` and `onDetach` but they are called after leaving the `Fragment`, so I cannot stop it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `parent Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();

     YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

}
```

Then you have access to your `Fragment` so you can add a parameter in your fragment `textHasChanged` (for example) and update it when the text changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may create interface which has method onBackPressed(your fragment should implement this interface), then override method onBackPressed in your activity, then find your fragment by tag or id -> cast to this interface and call this method.

Comment: but how do I find (in the parent Activity) the fragment which is currently being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

So you need `BackPressed()` event in fragment for you problem to check if editext is values is changed or not?

So you have create you own `OnBackpressed()` interface.

Create a interface `OnBackPressedListener`

```
public interface OnBackPressedListener {
    public void doBack();
}
```

Create a new class name `BaseBackPressedListener`

```
public class BaseBackPressedListener implements OnBackPressedListener {
    private final FragmentActivity activity;

    public BaseBackPressedListener(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void doBack() {
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
      //activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Create a instance of your newly created class `BaseBackPressedListener` in your top base Activity where fragment is added

```
protected OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener;
```

Create a method in your top base activity to set newly created instance of new class above

```
public void setOnBackPressedListener(OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener) {
    this.onBackPressedListener = onBackPressedListener;
}
```

you will have overide `onBackPressed()` method in you top base activity modify it like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (onBackPressedListener != null)
        onBackPressedListener.doBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
     }
```

And lastly you have add this in you fragment `onCreateView()`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();

    ((BaseActivity)activity).setOnBackPressedListener(new BaseBackPressedListener(activity));


    //your other stuff here

    return view;
}
```

Now you can check on back pressed in your top base activity weather editext value change our not by modifying this methods

```
 @Override
    public void doBack() {
    if(!IsEditTextChanged)
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
      //activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
```

IsEditTextChanged is global variable set its values on textchanged

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)
        IsEditTextChanged = true;
        // your desired logic here?
   }
  });
```

[Fragment BackPressed thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Boolean value in the FragmentActivity and keep it updated with the EditText updated. In this way you can check the String value instead the EditText (In fact the fragment could not be loaded in the Pager).

For example:

1) create an interface in order to declare the input protocol

```
public interface InputInterface {
    void setEditTextNotEmpty(Boolean notEmpty);
}
```

2) implement this interface in your FragmentActivity

```
public class MainActivity implements InputInterface {
private Boolean editTextNotEmpty;

...
@Override
void setEditTextNotEmpty(Boolean changed){
    editTextNotEmpty=changed;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ... your custom code....
}
```

3) You somehow notify the Fragment when it's visualized as for in this post: [How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)

When the fragment is visualized, you update the activity boolean if necessary.

4) keep your MainActivity updated when you update the edit text:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          if (getActivity instanceof InputInterface){
              Boolean notEmpty = !TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString);
             ((InputInterface)getActivity).setEditTextNotEmpty(notEmpty);
          }
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
```

I hope it helped.