# FragmentStatePagerAdapter is deprecated from API 27

Tags: android, android-support-library, fragmentstatepageradapter

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is deprecated from API 27. What's the alternative of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

```
private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment result = new DummyFragment();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Above code shows `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, `getItem(...)` and `super(...)` as deprecated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I had switched from v4 to v13, so that I could use standard fragments in the code (not the support fragments and the support fragment manager). Now it looks like I need to switch back to support fragments. At least half a day editing of code :-(

Comment: Refactored the code for Androidx support libraries, hopefully it remains stable for some time now.

Comment: If you use AndroidX, you may do it in such a way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131172/fragmentstatepageradapter-is-deprecated-from-api-27/56542546#56542546

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56208169/1318946

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT). 
BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, it means offset fragments will be executed on onStart() and the current fragment will be executed onStart() and onResume().

Comment: although now is deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Answer (score 86):

Switch to [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) and use [FragmentStateAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter) instead.

From there you can use onPause and onResume callbacks to determine which fragment is currently visible for the user. onResume is called when a fragment became visible and onPause when it stops to be visible. -> [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager/57888432#57888432)

Based on the comments of [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4233804/erik-jhordan-rey) and [Reejesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14784590/reejesh).

---

**Old answer (deprecated too now)**

The following constructors do the same

```
super(@NonNull FragmentManager fm)
super(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT)
```

Passing `BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT` got deprecated. You should pass **`BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`** instead.

The difference in passing those is explained in **`FragmentPagerAdapter`**:

```
 /**
 * Indicates that Fragment#setUserVisibleHint(boolean) will be 
 * called when the current fragment changes.
 */
@Deprecated
public static final int BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT = 0;

/**
 * Indicates that only the current fragment will be 
 * in the Lifecycle.State#RESUMED state. All other Fragments 
 * are capped at Lifecycle.State#STARTED.
 */
public static final int BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT = 1;
```

Comment: Does this affect the functionality in any way?

Comment: BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT it means offset fragments will be executed on onStart() and the current fragment will be executed unto onStart() and onResume().  about how it affects not really, depends your implementation.

Comment: although now is deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Google has made ```ViewPager2``` as a ```final``` class, We are not allowed to extend and modify its functionalities, which was possible earlier with ```ViewPager```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57888432/14784590 and we can use onPause and onResume

Answer (score 67):

You may extend

```
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
```

and call

```
super(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
```

in your class's constructor

Comment: But it is deprecated. What to use alternatively to FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: Could you please check your imports: are you using androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter or android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: You are right, it was the incorrect import. This does work.

Comment: Added this and a button in one of my fragments stopped responding to its onClick function

Comment: check out , looks like the answer is outdated. Still shows as deprecated crossed ` androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` on child

Answer (score 23):

This works for me.

In Kotlin :

```
class TasksPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT )
```

Comment: I use your  code but i got lint error "must be one of BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)"

what should i do?

Comment: getting error 
Must be one of: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT, androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT

Answer (score 22):

You need to add behavior in your `MainPagerAdapter` like this:

`super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);`

Answer (score 5):

The constructor with only FragmentManager as a paramaeter is duplicated and changed to

```
public FragmentStatePagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm,
        @Behavior int behavior)
```

but you can achieve the same by using the below constructor, you should also inject your tabsNumber via constructor to avoid using hard codded numbers, and return it via getCount().

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    this.numberOfTabs= NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
    public int getCount() {

        return numberOfTabs;
    }
```

for more details check the official documentation for [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

Android **ViewPager2** with **TabLayout** to implement `Fragments` in the `Activity`

**1. in your XML file inside vertical Linearlayout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_50"/>

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**2. Create your Adapter to load Fragments**

```
class MyFragmentsAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 2

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return if (position == 0) {
            FirstFragment()
        } else {
            SecondFragment()
        }

    }
}
```

**3. Paste this code into your Activity class and DONE!**

```
dataBinding.pager.adapter = PropertyDetailFragmentsAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

    TabLayoutMediator(dataBinding.tabLayout, dataBinding.pager) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = when (position) {
            0 -> "First Fragment"
            1 -> "Second Fragment"
            else -> "First Fragment"
        }
    }.attach()
```

Answer (score 2):

This class was deprecated in API level 27.1.0.
which was in support v13
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter from support v4
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter is deprecated also

Comment: I think that despite having had the wrong links (which I just fixed), this answer is correct: v4 FragmentStatePagerAdapter is not deprecated. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html @Ernesto I'm not sure which version of FragmentStatePagerAdapter your comment refers to.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

[See Reference developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

Answer (score 2):

I know that is an old question, but now both FragmentStatePagerAdapter constructors are deprecated.

Instead you may extend:

```
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
```

The constructor its a bit different:

```
class DemoCollectionAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    
          override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3
    
          override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> MyFragment()
                1 -> MyFragment2()
                2 -> MyFragment3()
            }
        }
    }
```

So in Fragment:

```
 class CollectionDemoFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var demoCollectionAdapter: DemoCollectionAdapter
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection_demo, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager)
        val tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)
        demoCollectionAdapter = DemoCollectionAdapter(this)
        
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = when (position) {
            0 -> "Home"
            1 -> "Search"
            2 -> "Favorites"
        }
        }.attach()
        
        viewPager.adapter = demoCollectionAdapter
    }
}
```

And change the xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Check it the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter was deprecated.

You may replace it with android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.

[Check this out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter) for Official doumentation.

Answer (score 0):

Both `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` have been deprecated. We need to use `ViewPager2 + FragmentStateAdapter` since AndroidX

Here are two ways to implement the above:

1. This link is a vast solution including the implementation of `TabLayout` with `ViewPager2`. This also includes various updates throughout

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54643817/8664401

2. This tutorial is a relatively simpler implementation to resolve the issue and discusses an approach to `ViewPager2` with `Fragment`

- https://androidwave.com/viewpager2-with-fragments-android-example/

Both the solutions work. Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) too for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

**To load single Fragment at a time you have to use `ViewPager2`. Because `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`  is deprecated after API level 27.**

Use Below steps to implement `viewPager` with `TabLayout` to load single fragment at time.

**Step1:** add tablayout nad viewpage in your xml file where you want to display multiple tab.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
 android:id="@+id/tab_layout"/> 

 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:saveEnabled="false"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/viewpager"     />
```

**Step2:** Then Create Adapter Class for your viewPager to manage your multiple Fragments.

```
class MyFragmentsAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, 
        private val totalTabs: Int, 
        lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

override fun getItemCount(): Int = totalTabs

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
     when (position) {
        0 -> {
            return NotificationsFragment()
        }
        1 -> {
            return MessagesFragment()
        }
        2 -> {
            return CalendarFragment()

        }
        else -> return NotificationsFragment()
    }
  } 
}
```

**Step3:** Now attached this adapter class with your viewPager Object.

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.notification)))
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.messages)))
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.calendar)))
    val adapter = NotificationTabsAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        childFragmentManager, tabLayout.tabCount,
        lifecycle
    )

    viewPager.adapter = adapter
```

**Step4:** Now create `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback` method to manage tablayout status on ViewPager state change. Also register this method for viewpager using `registerOnPageChangeCallback`

```
        val myPageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position)?.select()
        }
    }
    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(myPageChangeCallback)
```

**Step5:** Now Register tablyout  to change viewpager on tabItem click.

```
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }
    })
```