# 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)' is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Recently the `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager` is deprecated and no proper solutions are available.

Have tried to implement support V4 but did not work with `AndroidX`. It shows library not found.

PagerAdapter:

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
    //...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` have been deprecated. We need to use `ViewPager2 + FragmentStateAdapter` since **AndroidX**. Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66545099/8664401

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Recently the androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager is deprecated

It is not deprecated at the present time. For example, [it is not marked as deprecated in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager).

> 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)' is deprecated

The single-parameter `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` constructor is deprecated. However, if you [read the documentation for that constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html#FragmentStatePagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)), you will find:

> This constructor is deprecated.
>   use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html#FragmentStatePagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%2520int)) with BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT

So, replace `FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm)` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)`, to retain the functionality from the original one-parameter constructor.

Comment: Thanks, can try super(fm,FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);

Comment: today replace this:

super(fm,FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);

to this:

super(fm,FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);

the answer is also deprecated now

Answer (score 15):

You can change default constructor as below:

```
public SectionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior, Context mContext) {
    super(fm, behavior);
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

Full Adapter class as defined:

```
/**
 * A [FragmentPagerAdapter] that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2};
    private final Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior, Context mContext) {
        super(fm, behavior);
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a ProductSearchFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        if(position == 0) {
            return new ProductSearchFragment();
        } else if(position == 1) {
            return new GenericSearchFragment();
        }
        return new ProductSearchFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }
}
```

and You can call like:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, this);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

    super(fm);
}
```

With

```
public SectionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm,
                            int behavior) {
    super(fm,behavior);
}
```

Alternatively you can go

Right Click -> Generate -> Override Methods and click on the first item as shown in the image.[image]

You may need to change your code in other places after doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution in Kotlin :

```
class TasksPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT )
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem.

Change:

```
private class TestTest extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

To:

```
private class TestTest extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
```

It will change:

```
import androidx.legacy.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
```

To:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```