# API calls in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` and used `FragmentPagerAdapter`, now I have 4 fragments and in every fragment, I need to make an HTTP request, I don't want to hit all the API for 4 fragments at a time instead I require to hit the API only when the respective fragment is the current item visible.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You can use 'setUserVisibleHint' method in the Fragment

Comment: [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)