# Retrive data from activity every time oncreateViwe of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, interface, fragment

**Activity**

```
public class GroupesActivity extends BaseActivity {
SelectedBundle selectedBundle;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_groupes);
        sectionsPagerAdapter = new GroupPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    
}
 private void getAllGroup() {
// api call retrive data
        // send data using interface on response     
        //   set data         selectedBundle.onBundleSelect(isVisible,calanderModelList,groupModelList,eventModelList);

}

  public void setOnBundleSelected(SelectedBundle selectedBundle) {
        this.selectedBundle = selectedBundle;
    }

    public interface SelectedBundle {
        void onBundleSelect(boolean isVisible, List<CalanderModel> calanderModelList, List<GroupModel> groupModelList, List<EventModel> eventModelList);
    }


}
```

**Frgment**

```
    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_groups_fragments, container, false);

// get data only once on oncreateview 

      ((GroupesActivity) getActivity()).setOnBundleSelected(new GroupesActivity.SelectedBundle() {
                @Override
                public void onBundleSelect(boolean isVisible, List<CalanderModel> calanderModelListtt, List<GroupModel> groupModelList, List<EventModel> eventModelList) {
    
                    Log.e("retrive data","data")
                }
            });
    
    return root;
    }
    }
```

**GroupPagerAdapter**

```
public class GroupPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2, R.string.tab_text_3};
    private final Context mContext;

    public GroupPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super( fm);
        this.mContext=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new AllGroupsFragments();
            case 1:
                return new HostFragments();
            case 2:
                return new GuestFragments();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

**problem**

> i have three fragments in tabview  when i swipe this obove fragment
> and then come again in this fragmnet that interface not called and i'm
> not getting data from activity
>
> How to get that data again from its parent activity, i need to only
> retrive that data from activity on each time of fragments oncreateView

**Thanks in adavance  ;)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `setMenuVisibility()` method in Fragment to fix the issue.

```
//In fragments
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean isVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(isVisible);
    if (isVisible) {
        //visible to user- do ur stuff
        ((GroupesActivity) getActivity()).setOnBundleSelected(new 
           GroupesActivity.SelectedBundle() {
            @Override
            public void onBundleSelect(boolean isVisible, List<CalanderModel> 
                calanderModelListtt, List<GroupModel> groupModelList, List<EventModel> 
                eventModelList) {

                Log.e("retrive data","data")
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the following link may help if you face any issues:
[How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but it gives NullPointerException:  on interface method with  on a null object reference at setOnBundleSelected

Comment: Can you share logcat log?

Comment: problem is what when i go on fragment three by swiping tabview and again i came on fragment one it creates again and that time this interface method didn't called

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.activity.GroupesActivity.setOnBundleSelected(com.activity.GroupesActivity$SelectedBundle)' on a null object reference
        at com.illumaworks.Whenis.fragments.AllGroupsFragments.setMenuVisibility(AllGroupsFragments.java:96)

Comment: is there any other way to get data from parent activity again when fragment creates?

Comment: Error you are facing bcz, sometimes setMenuVisibility get triggered before `onCreateView`

Comment: There is a workaround you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25101237/6611986

let me know if you are still facing issues

Comment: not worked problem is what my fragment didn't call on resume it calls every time when i came back onCreateView, check i also added code of pager adapter in question